# adding Admob to Libgdx game

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I was fallowing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwAN4LMXo58) but when I tried to go to monetize page I wasn't able to monetize or add any banner because my game isn't in the store unlike the tutorial.

My question is: do I need to upload my game without adding the code of admob then add it latter to my game or shall I add the code before uploading it then set the things  from admob website?

It might be a silly question but I'm just a newbie when it comes to admob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hole section in Libgdx official docs that explain how to use Admob :

- [Admob in libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)

consider that :

> Android (6.4.1 and earlier SDKs) Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google
>   Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old
>   standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to
>   the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.

According to Libgdx wiki :

> Barebones Sample App
>
> I created a new libgdx project using gdx-setup-ui.jar, added a
>   .gitignore file, and made my initial commit.
>
> Eclipse Setup
>
> In eclipse, import the barebones sample app (file > import > existing
>   projects into workspace) - you should now have at least three projects
>   in package explorer (core, android, and desktop).
>
> Open the Android SDK Manager, download the latest SDK Platform and
>   Google APIs (at time of writing: 4.4.2/API19), the 2.3.1/API9 SDK
>   Platform, and from Extras - Google Play Services.
>
> Locate the
>   /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
>   directory on your machine (on my windows machine - C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib)
>   and copy into your working directory alongside the existing libgdx
>   projects.
>
> File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code, Next, Browse,
>   navigate to the local copy of google-play-services_lib in your working
>   directory, Ok, Finish.
>
> Right-click your android project, select Properties, Android, scroll
>   down and click Add, select the google-play-services_lib project, Ok.
>
> A refresh and clean in eclipse probably wouldn't hurt at this point,
>   so go ahead and do that.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Ensure that the target in android project's project.properties file is
>   at least 13, and the android:minSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml
>   is at least 9. Sadly this does mean users running ancient versions of
>   Android will be excluded, but there's nothing we can do about this.
>   There are very very VERY few devices still running versions below
>   2.3/API9, so at least you won't be excluding many users...
>
> Add these two lines as children of the 'application' element:
>
> Add these two permissions as children of the 'manifest' element:
>
> Save changes, then refresh and clean in eclipse for good luck...
>
> Banner Ad
>
> [See this version of the android project's MainActivity class](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java) for a
>   reasonably straightforward banner ad implementation.
>
> Interstitial Ad
>
> [This diff shows an interstitial ad implementation](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/commit/0a5ea376d4eb92b8e87c13a03245adb40b53e811) (ActionResolver
>   interface lets us trigger interstitial actions from the core project
>   while retaining the invaluable LibGdx cross-platform functionality).
>
> That's all there is to it!
>
> One final note if cloning from
>   https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads, pay
>   attention to the problems view in eclipse! You will need to create an
>   empty 'gen' directory in both the google-play-services_lib and
>   tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android projects, and ensure you have the
>   required android sdks installed. As is often the case with eclipse, a
>   liberal amount of refreshing and cleaning will do no harm...