# Cannot find a way to import google services api library into eclipse

Tags: libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I wanted to import admob to my libgdx project in eclipse, so I went to the documentation of libgdx, on this page: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29
I couldn't get far through the instructions... Apparently google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib is replaced with m2repository\com\google\android\gms. Now I have to import this directory into the eclipse workspace. Going to import.../Android/Existing Android Code into Workspace doesn't work, so my question is how I should import this directory otherwise. I hope someone knows how to do that, and I would really appreciate an answer. But reckon that I will have many other struggles going through the rest of the instructions.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Be aware that [Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse may prevent you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project. To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers. Now, for your problem about admob, I think this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733006) can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me! I would move over to Android Studio, but would I then still be able to develop iOS games with admob?

Comment: Yes that is possible, I did it with the [Multi-OS Engine](http://multi-os-engine.org/)